# Pass pointer to data as argument to function expecting two-dimensional array

Tags: c++

Consider the following code

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<array>

void show(double x[2][2]) {
  std::cout<<x[0][0]<<", "<<x[0][1]<<std::endl
           <<x[1][0]<<", "<<x[1][1]<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::array<double, 4> y = {1, 2, 3, 4};  
  double x[2][2];

  // it is safe to copy because x[2][2] consists of
  // four contiguous blocks of memory in row-major order

  std::copy(y.begin(), y.end(), &x[0][0]);

  show(x); // this, obviously, works as expected

  // but how can I cast y, or y.data(),
  // or y.begin() to use the function foo?    
  // show(y); 
}
```

I am working with a legacy library where a lot of function arguments are like `x[a][b]`. However, my code relies on linear data representations (that is, I only use C++ "linear" containers, such as `std::array<T, N>`).

Imagine that after laborious calculations I have reached a point in the code where `std::array<double, 2>` contains the data that I need, and now I need to call `foo` on that data.

How can I "cast" (for lack of a better word) the underlying container so that I can call the legacy function which expects a `double[2][2]`?

I really don't want to take copies (as shown in the example) because the legacy functions such as `foo` are called hundreds of thousands of times.

As an extreme plus, I would like to wrap these legacy functions behind a C++ algorithm-like interface; something along the lines of:

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 4>> z;
fooify(z.begin(), z.end()); // calls foo(zi) for each zi in z
```

#### Edit: some answers

Thanks to @6502, I am starting with a solution along the lines of:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<array>

namespace legacy {
void show(double x[2][2]) {
  std::cout<<x[0][0]<<", "<<x[0][1]<<std::endl
           <<x[1][0]<<", "<<x[1][1]<<std::endl;
}
}

template<size_t N, typename Container>
void show(Container& y) {
  return legacy::show(reinterpret_cast<double(*)[N]>(y.data()));
}

int main() {
  std::array<double, 4> y = {1, 2, 3, 4};  
  show<2>(y);
}
```

which works as expected --- of course, I can automatically deduce the "re-shaping" factor (in this case it is 2, but it will vary in the general case).

Then I will try to incorporate this "refactored" function into an algorithm.

For completeness, I add the compilation details (OS X 10.7.4 using GCC 4.8.1):

```
$ g++ example.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra
$ ./a.out                                                 
1, 2
3, 4
```

Comment: `f(T a[2][2])` is in reality `f(T (* a)[2])` – and you *should* use the signature to make this clear, rather than the wholly misleading syntax `a[2][2]` (which should really be deprecated since it’s effectively lying to the programmer). This shows that the types are really incompatible.

Comment: I understand the problem, but just to clarify, you want to pass a linear array of *two* elements to a function that in reality expects *four* (the data coalesce is a side--show, but this is rather important).

Comment: @WhozCraig The other way round, surely? `show` expects an array of two pointers, and OP is trying to pass an array of four `double`s.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `show()` expects one pointer; not an array of two pointers. This is a *real* 2D array. And the OP changed the `std::array<>` decl to account for the space discrepancy from `2` to `4`, so that answers my question, and was likely just a typo on his part.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah yes, a pointer to array. Still, incompatible types.

Comment: @KonradRudolph incompatible because one is `double (*)[2]` and one is simply `double *` ? Agreed they're different, but doesn't std array guarantee continuity?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, I’m being stupid. Ignore me.

Comment: @KonradRudolph heh. not like i've never had similar moments. Tis' all good. Keeps us humble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using C-style casting

```
show((double (*)[2])y.data());
```

or using `reinterpret_cast` if you like to type more

```
show(reinterpret_cast<double (*)[2]>(y.data()));
```

Comment: I don’t think the two are layout-compatible. This cast will fail.

Comment: The C-style cast works for me, no warnings using -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 (my "de facto" flags) in GCC 4.8.1.

Comment: Yeah, no compiler error, my mistake. But a nice segfault at runtime.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: IMO if it's good enough for `copy` it must work. I don't use C++11 and I don't know `std::array` guarantees. On my `gcc` compiles and works as expected, clearly a pointer to a double is compatible with a pointer to an array of two doubles (if it's pointing to two consecutive doubles, that is).

Comment: @6502 The `copy` is a completely different case. There, OP is copying from a `[2][2]` array (which is contiguous in memory), not a pointer-to-array.

Comment: If this works for `show()` under gcc, is it guaranteed to be portable?

Comment: I wouldn't use a C-style-cast, and `reinterpret_cast<>` is a pretty big hammer, rarely needed for something like this.

Comment: Just to clarify, my assertions that this “doesn’t work” were actually based on a test – unfortunately, I had failed to remove a previous test which passed `nullptr` to the function. So all is good. This does work, and as WhozCraig explains in a comment below the answer, the layout incompatibility is actually not a problem here. This might still be UB (the specs for `reinterpret_cast` are hard to read but I cannot find anything allowing this conversion) but it works on GCC and probably every sane compiler.

Comment: @WhozCraig: This is in my opinion the perfect case in which you should use `reinterpret_cast` (or a C-style cast). Clearly from a philosophical point of view a 2x2 array is totally unrelated to a 4-element array, but still the layout in memory is identical and this is a case where you need to tell the compiler to ignore types and trust the programmer.

Comment: @6502 I agree - this seems to be a case in which I need the compiler to trust me, without warnings, and using standard-compliant code.

Comment: @6502 So you're saying a properly formed `static_cast<>` would *not* work ?

Comment: @WhozCraig: a `double *` and a pointer to an array of two doubles are completely different and unrelated types (because a double and an array of two doubles are unrelated types) and `static_cast` cannot do a conversion between them. `reinterpret_cast` can instead do a conversion between any two pointer types: the result can be meaningful or not, and in this case it is meaningful.

Comment: @6502 So then that would be "no, static_cast won't work" then. I understand. The specific error clang will report, btw, is "static cast from `double *` to `double (*)[2]` is not allowed. After your last comment that makes complete sense. Thanks for clarifying.